# How to auto add the parentheses after if/for/while in CLion?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, jetbrains-ide

When I use the IDEA, type the `if/for/while`, the parentheses will auto added.But CLion will not auto complete.

IDEA

[image]

CLion

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I want the Clion to auto add the parenthesis when type the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use complete statement ([`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html)).

```
void foo() {
  if|<Ctrl+Shift+Enter>
}
```

generates

```
void foo() {
  if (true|<Ctrl+Shift+Enter>) {
  }
}
```

one more complete moves you into the block:

```
void foo() {
  if (true) {
    |
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it automatic?

Comment: You are right. This functionality need to be implemented. The issue 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5464
is connected with your case. Please, vote!

Answer (score 0):

It can be found in Settings/Editor/General/Smart Keys (Or just go to Help-> Find -> Smart Keys)

There you have an option to check `Home`, `End (on blank line)`, `Insert pair bracket`, etc. Check `Insert pair bracket`. This should do it.